# Visual Studio Installer stuck at Windows SDK

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-installer

my Visual Studio Installer has been stuck on this screen for a long time. I tried to install "Desktop Development with C++" and its tools but it's stuck on Windows SDK (package 426 out of 427). [image: Image for reference].
I looked on Google and one solution told to check for windows update. So I did, and my Windows is fully updated.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily live without that version, I recommend 10.0.19041.  If that hangs too then use another machine.